# How to send parameter from action in rendering method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

How to send parameter in render a view from action

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @donation.save
  else
    format.html { render :new,:locals => { :need_id => @need_id }}
  end
end
```

But `need_id` is accessble in `new.html.erb`
How I pass this param?

Comment: instance var will travel to view by itself isn't ?

Comment: in else just decalre your variable eg.   else     @need_id = params[:donation][:need_id]

Answer (score 1):

If you have already defined `@need_id` in your controller. It will be  available in the corresponding view files as it is:

View file (.html.erb):

```
<%= @need_id %>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `@need_id` is not nil inside controller just before render step?

Answer (score 0):

If you have @need_id in the controller and this

```
format.html { render :new,:locals => { :need_id => @need_id }}
```

you can do <%= need_id %> in view file.